# "logger" differences betw script and command line

Tags: bash, scripts, syslog

If I enter from the command line

```
logger "This is a test"
```

in my syslog I get:

```
Aug  9 07:54:22 computername root: This is a test
```

but if I use the exact same line in a script, when the script is run, I get:

```
Aug  9 08:00:01 computername root: This is a test
Aug  9 08:00:01 computername sSMTP[3820]: Creating SSL connection to host
Aug  9 08:00:01 computername sSMTP[3820]: SSL connection using DHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Aug  9 08:00:03 computername sSMTP[3820]: Sent mail for someone@somewhere.com (221 2.0.0 mx4.smtphost.com cmsmtp closing connection) uid=0 username=root outbytes=642
```

Can someone enlighten me as to what is happening here?  How do I prevent invoking mail command?

Ubuntu 16.04, munged names to anonymize the log data...

Comment: The settings for that are apparently in /etc/rsyslog.d , see https://serverfault.com/a/264966/363611 and comments below the answer. Let us know if this helps

Comment: Sergiy thank you, but the linked article seems to be about configuring logging - I am not worried about whether or not I log the email send (I actually like it logging that) but instead why does logger appear to invoke the sending of an email message when logger is called from a script, but not when it is called from CLI?

Comment: That's a good question, to which I don't have an answer, but only a guess that this may have something to do with shell being non-interactive ( which is what scripts are - non-interactive shell instance ), or potentially  something to do with environment variables, which makes more sense.

Comment: Note that the email related messages are issued by `sSMTP` (PID 3820), not your program. Does your script output stuff to STDOUT that `cron` wants to email to you?

Comment: waltinator, thank you much, this appears to be the answer.  I have learned something valuable from this!  Apparently cron does indeed try to email stdout.  If I remove any echoed output from the script, the ssmtp does not get called from the script.  Thank you!!